# <a> element cause shift on click

Tags: css, html

I have an `<ul>` with three `<li>` on the inside.

All three are `<a>` elements and when I click on them, it causes whatever is on the right side of them to shift right.

## HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">About Maze</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#footer ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}

#footer li {
float: left;
}

#footer li a {
display: block;
}
```

Tested this in Canary, Chrome, IE and Firefox. Putting this code through JSFiddle shows no issue.

Why is this occuring, and how can I fix it?

Comment: jsfiddle not show any issue here, http://jsfiddle.net/uVQvE/

Comment: When you tested, was it with this exact code or are you showing a simplified version?

Comment: If 'putting it through JSFiddle shows issue', please provide us with a demo which does demonstrate what you're having problems with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you have no css for a:hover or a:active

It would be better to have a link to where the actual problem is, because as you say there is no issue with this code in jsfiddle.

-- after i saw actual code...

Its because you had a :active and :visited selectors all coupled in one css rule with 20px margin-right. So when you click it was adding 20px margin-right > updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3t4bf/1/

old code:

```
#nav li a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #3498db;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

new code:

```
#nav li a:link{
    color: #3498db;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#nav li a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #3498db;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Huge oversight on my part. This was simplified code, but you mentioning a:active is what made me realise I messed up. Thank you.

Comment: no worries, sometimes you can be staring at your own code and not realise the simplest thing thats going on, i do it all the time. Then someone mentions something and it was so obvious :)

Comment: Hmm.. it worked for a second, until I refreshed then it went back to doing it again. 

I managed to replicate it in JSFiddle ->http://jsfiddle.net/3t4bf/

Comment: Its because you have visited and active all coupled together in one css rule with margin:20px so when you click it is essentially adding another 20px on to it.